# Find last occurrence of any item of one list in another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following 2 lists in python:

```
ll = [500,500,500,501,500,502,500]
mm = [499,501,502]
```

I want to find out the position of last occurence of any item in mm, in the list ll. I can do this for a single element like this:

```
len(ll) - 1 - ll[::-1].index(502)
>> 5
```

Here ll[::-1].index(502) provides position of last occurence of 502 and len(ll) - 1 gives the total length.

How do I extend this to work for the entire list mm? I know I can write a function, but is there a more pythonic way

Comment: `len(ll) - 1 - ll[::-1].index(502)` Whoa there. Can you please start by explaining that?

Comment: I think you can just use `ll.rindex(502)` to find the last index ... none of that weird mumbo jumbo you got up there

Comment: thanks @JoranBeasley, that is much simpler

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Comment: @Apero oh your right my mistake apparently its only for strings

Comment: This could have been the solution if ll was containing single digit numbers as well as mm, and if you had done ''.join(ll).rindex(500) for example

Comment: @Joran you can *emulate* an `.rindex` using something like `next((-i + len(ll) - 1 for i, v in enumerate(reversed(ll)) if v==502))` - but you'll get a `StopIteration` instead of `ValueError` if an element isn't present - but it saves forcing reverse slicing the list

Comment: @Joran or instead of the `-1` in the calc (which only gets executed when the condition is met anyway) you can just start the `enumerate` from `1` instead of `0` (and you could also use a negatively stepped `range` then index back to `ll` for checking as the loop criteria...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want *all* the *last* indices of each item in `ll` present in `mm`, then:

```
ll = [500,500,500,501,500,502,500]
mm = [499,501,502]

d = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(ll) if v in mm}
# {501: 3, 502: 5}
```

It's probably worth creating a `set` from `mm` first to make it an O(1) lookup, instead of O(N), but for three items, it's really not worth it.

Following @Apero's concerns about retaining missing indices as `None` and also using a hash lookup to make it an `O(1)` lookup...

```
# Build a key->None dict for all `mm`
d = dict.fromkeys(mm)
# Update `None` values with last index using a gen-exp instead of dict-comp
d.update((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(ll) if v in d)
# {499: None, 501: 3, 502: 5}
```

Comment: In what this is better than my answer which ensures none of the searched values are lost in the results? Also, this method makes ou go over the entire ll list and also overwrite the dict key/value on each iteration

Comment: @Apero because the absence of a key is the absence of an index... and it's O(N)... your approach of reversing the list and then `.index`ing each time is expensive - plus you're using exceptions to handle a complicated control flow that can be handled by the dict-comp naturally

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot I used the reverse, which is heavy too. Good point. But as a user, I'd like to see that a key hasn't been found. What could we do to improve your answer do handle this? Just curious

Comment: @Apero updated answer to reflect your concerns - hope that helps

Comment: Really neat, I was just trying to leverage fromkeys but didn't think about update with a generator. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
results = {}
reversed = ll[::-1]

for item in mm:
    try:
        index = ((len(ll) - 1) - reversed.index(item))
    except ValueError:
        index = None
    finally:
        results[item] = index

print results
```

Output:

```
{499: None, 501: 3, 502: 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension and the `max` function. In particular, for each element in `ll`, iterate through `mm` to create a list of indices where `ll[i] = mm[i]`, and take the `max` of this list.

```
>>> indices = [ max([-1] + [i for i, m in enumerate(mm) if m == n])  for n in ll ]
>>> indices
[-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 2, -1]
```

Note that you need to add `[-1]` in case there are no matching indices in `mm`.

All this being said, I don't think it's more Python-ic than writing a function and using a list comprehension (as you alluded to in your question).